# How different is iOS 4 from iOS 3?

Tags: iphone, ios

I relatively new to iOS development and I have been learning iOS 4 for a few weeks now.  With the imminent release of iOS 5 looming I was wondering, based on hindsight(iOS 3 -> 4), how different they(iOS 4 -> 5) might be.

Comment: [What's New in iOS 4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/whats-new.html)

Comment: iOS4 was 33% better than iOS3. iOS5 will only be 25% better than iOS4 but a whopping 66% better than iOS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences from iOS 3-4 are pretty large. The main change was the implementation of multitasking. Based on this, changes from iOS 4-5 will most likely include at least one big change and lots of smaller changes, as this is the way apple does things.

Comment: next question..should I be worried about unlearning what I've learnt until 5 is released?

Comment: Definitely not, everything is backward compatible, therefore if your code works on iOS 3.0 it will work on 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, and so on

Comment: Cool, Thanks! had me worried!

Answer (score 0):

they release over 100 features apparently within ios, development wise, the updating of a project from IOS 3 to IOS 4 to incorporate alot of new features took its time

Answer (score 0):

For developers, they'll probably be quite different. Aside from the major new features in OS4, there are all sorts of little APIs that are lovely to use and really annoying to not use when supporting OS3! For example, gesture recognisers. (Yes, they're in OS3.2, but that was iPad only. Ditto for Core Text.)

Comment: Reminds me of trying to do browser compatibility CSS hodge-podge, Thanks!

Comment: At least with the iOS stuff there's a definite way to check if each one is supported.